# using user input to convert hex (0x) or binary (0b) to decimal numbers

Tags: java, binary, hex, decimal

user enters a number in either hex or binary (must be prefixed with 0x or 0b, if not gives the error message). 
read user input as a string

i can't use radix, i'm just using integer.parseInt(s)

i am not sure how to make this program work.. please help
what am i missing here?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class conversion {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //ask user to enter either hex or binary
    System.out.println("Please enter a hex (0x) or binary (0b) number: ");

    //read input as string
    String hexString = input.nextLine();
    String binString = input.nextLine();


    //if prefix (0x)
    if ((hexString.substring(0,2)).equals("0x")) {
        int hex = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
        System.out.println("Converting from base-16 to base-10.\n" + hex);

        //if there are no digits or invalid digits after Ox
        //if ((hexString.substring(beginIndex))) {
        //  System.out.println("Error parsing base-16 number");
        //}

    //if prefix (0b)    
    } else if ((binString.substring(0,2)).equals("0b")) {
        int bin = Integer.parseInt(binString, 2);
        System.out.println("Converting from base-2 to base-10.\n" + bin);

        //if there are no digits or invalid digits after Ob
        //if ((binString.substring(beginIndex))) {
        //  System.out.println("Error parsing base-2 number");
        //}


    } else {
        System.out.println("I don't know how to covert that number");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because you are trying to convert the whole string including 0x or 0b. You need to remove it from your string before converting. Here is the full working example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask user to enter either hex or binary
        System.out.println("Please enter a hex (0x) or binary (0b) number: ");

        //read input as string
        String hexString = input.nextLine();
        String binString = input.nextLine();

        //if prefix (0x)
        if (hexString.startsWith("0x")) {
            hexString = hexString.replaceAll("0x", "");
            int hex = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
            System.out.println("Converting from base-16 to base-10.\n" + hex);

            //if there are no digits or invalid digits after Ox
            //if ((hexString.substring(beginIndex))) {
            //  System.out.println("Error parsing base-16 number");
            //}
            //if prefix (0b)    
        } else if (binString.startsWith("0b")) {
            binString = binString.replaceAll("0x", "");
            int bin = Integer.parseInt(binString, 2);
            System.out.println("Converting from base-2 to base-10.\n" + bin);

            //if there are no digits or invalid digits after Ob
            //if ((binString.substring(beginIndex))) {
            //  System.out.println("Error parsing base-2 number");
            //}
        } else {
            System.out.println("I don't know how to covert that number");
        }
    }
```

Allso to optimise your code you don't need to use `input.nextLine();` two times like you do here:

```
    //read input as string
    String hexString = input.nextLine();
    String binString = input.nextLine();
```

But you could use single string input like:
            //read input as string
            String consoleInput = input.nextLine();

```
        //if prefix (0x)
        if (consoleInput.startsWith("0x")) {
            consoleInput = consoleInput.replaceAll("0x", "");
            // ...
        } else if (consoleInput.startsWith("0b")) {
            consoleInput = consoleInput.replaceAll("0x", "");
            int bin = Integer.parseInt(consoleInput, 2);
            // ...
        } else {
            System.out.println("I don't know how to covert that number");
        }
```

I'ts allso nice to add try catch if for some reason user input can't be converted. Here is an working example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //ask user to enter either hex or binary
        System.out.println("Please enter a hex (0x) or binary (0b) number: ");

        //read input as string
        String consoleInput = input.nextLine();

        //if prefix (0x)
        if (consoleInput.startsWith("0x")) {
            consoleInput = consoleInput.replaceAll("0x", "");

            try {
                int hex = Integer.parseInt(consoleInput, 16);
                System.out.println("Converting from base-16 to base-10.\n" + hex);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error converting string: " + consoleInput);
            }

        } else if (consoleInput.startsWith("0b")) {
            consoleInput = consoleInput.replaceAll("0x", "");

            try {
                int bin = Integer.parseInt(consoleInput, 2);
                System.out.println("Converting from base-2 to base-10.\n" + bin);
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error converting string: " + consoleInput);
            }

        } else {
            System.out.println("I don't know how to covert that number");
        }
    }
```

Comment: oh thank you! @Kiki
how can i add concepts where if user input prefix 0x or 0b doesn't have digits after, or has invalid digits, so that i can tell them it's not possible to convert?

Comment: Add this just before convertion   if (consoleInput.trim().isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Can't convert");
                return;
            } Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpfull :)

Comment: I am sorry to bombarding you with questions.. just got lost, so if i want to add the part where if the input does not have a valid prefix… or if it has a valid prefix, but no digits are present after the prefix (only 0x or 0b, without anything after), end the program and say I don't know how to covert that number & 
if the input contains invalid digits for the specified base (for example F, or 15, for 0b, or base-2), end the program with the message Error conversion, do i have to have more complex codes or is there a simple way to do it? @Kiki